# Smooth Scrolling To Internal Links at other pages

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, smoothing

Im looking for a solution so i can smoothley scroll to an internal link on another html page.
I've founnd code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash,
    $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
```

});

But the problem with this code is that it doesnt work when you first put the html file name and than the internal link after the href. I have anchors like these:

```
<a href='blabla.html#bla1'>Blabla link</a>
```

I can't find a solution to this problem. I've searched the whole internet for an answer but i couldn't find it. Is it possible to rewrite this code so i can use it with hyperlinks? I need to do this in jQuery.

Comment: you have to set smooth scrolling code logic in the targeted page

Comment: JS is client side and its behavior isn't going to extend to the new page.  You need to add JS on the page being linked to that looks for a hash in the URL and scrolls to that element.